# Index.php automatically downloaded while installing opencart for the first time

Tags: nginx, opencart

I have a problem with Opencart installation.
I configured it with NGINX and after I finished the tutorial installation, I was unable to open it on my localhost. When I tried to open it, I downloaded the index.php file automatically.

I hope anyone have a solution for this.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you install the `php5-fpm` for nginx? What is your OpenCart nginx configuration?

Answer (score 0):

It's not about Opencart installation, it's about executing php file on nginx, you should install php5-fpm and have correct configurations. More info at http://apmblog.compuware.com/2014/10/30/proper-configuration-running-php-nginx/